# How can change in direction of force on pulley affect this situation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, constrained-dynamics

This problem (the b part) asks me to find the acceleration of the blocks but I'm quite not able to understand 2 thing

1.how the change in direction of F will cause the change of acceleration.

2. How to judge whether kinetic or static friction is operating

---

I dont want the solution for it but the basic idea of how the change in this force can cause a change in equation
[image]

---

For the determination of friction the general way to us is to assume that they move together then find common acceleration and again putting this acceleration in an equation to check whether friction coming out is greater than or less than static friction but here net force on system is upwards so:

### my equations

For $m_1$

- $F$-$f_s$=$m_1a$

---

For $m_2$

- $T$+$f_s$=$m_2 a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for (b) part.
Finding whether static or kinetic friction will be involved is easy.
[image]

We can see that pulling up results in the lower mass $m_2$ moving backwards and $m_1$ moving forwards. So the masses are surely going to slip.
Only reason to not slip would be if $F < \mu_s m_1 g$ which does not seem to be the case.

The reason why direction of $F$ matters can be understood if we consider (just for understanding) that the friction between $m_1$ and $m_2$ is so high that they don't slip. Then in case (1), the string would not even move and it would be equivalent to pulling $m_1 + m_2$ with a force $F$ horizontally. In case (2), If we imagine the blocks to not slip as previous, then F is basically trying to lift the system up and we won't have horizontal acceleration. Hope you understood why direction matters.

The reaction force on pulley1 would be different in both cases and since that pulley is attached to the mass itself, it makes a difference. ie: in case(2) $F_2$ would be along $X$ and that would also contribute to Acceleration.

Comment: Okay I'm pretty clear about the picture but could you give me a bit more idea of calculating normal force on pulley

Comment: for case (1) : $F_2$ would be horizontal and to the right with magnitude $F$.  $F_1$ would be at $45^o$ with a value $\sqrt{2} F$.    for case(2) : $F_2$ would be upwards with magnitude $2F$ and it would not contribute to horizontal acceleration. $F_1$ would be same . $\sqrt{2} F$.

Comment: Do not forget the friction force acting on $m_2$.

Comment: @RishabNavaneet it would be great if you add that in the answer

Comment: Thankyou @R.W. Bird. Also, to mention, I had a confusion whether the net upward force of $F$ on $m_2$ would increase the normal reaction between $m_1$ and $m_2$ and thereby increase the friction. But we need to consider that only if that upward force is greater than the weight. Only then would $m_1$ push on $m_2$

Answer (score 1):

In part a, the tension in the rope acts to the right on the lower pulley and to the left on the upper pulley.  The vertical forces are equal and opposite.  The tension is larger than the allowed static friction. $m_1$ accelerates to the right and is subject to kinetic friction which also accelerates $m_2$.
In part b, the tension is less than the weight. There is no vertical motion. The tension between $m_1$ and the upper pulley accelerates $m_1$ to the right and $m_2$ to the left. Again each is subject to kinetic friction.